# How to generate text and timing diagram together using tikz-timing package?

Tags: diagrams, tikz-timing

I am new to TeX and I am trying to create a document which has regular text, paragraphs etc and also a timing diagram somewhere in between. I am using the TikZ timing package.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

Create a section. Write some text. Add a timing diagram. End section and on to the next section.

Here is the code sample I tried.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}[2009/12/09]
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength{\PreviewBorder}{1mm}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
%
% Defining foreground (fg) and background (bg) colors
\definecolor{bgblue}{rgb}{0.41961,0.80784,0.80784}%
\definecolor{bgred}{rgb}{1,0.61569,0.61569}%
\definecolor{fgblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.6}%
\definecolor{fgred}{rgb}{0.6,0,0}%
%


\begin{section} 
1.  Timing diagram of SR Flip Flop
    Here is the timing diagram of SR flip flop.  


\begin{tikztimingtable}[
    timing/slope=0,         % no slope
    timing/coldist=2pt,     % column distance
    xscale=2.05,yscale=1.1, % scale diagrams
    semithick               % set line width
  ]
  \scriptsize clock     & 7{C}                              \\
  S                     & [fgblue] .75L h 2.25L H LLl       \\
  R                     & [fgblue]  1.8L .8H 2.2L 1.4H 0.8L \\
  Q                     &          L .8H 1.7L 1.5H LL       \\
  $\overline{\mbox{Q}}$ &          H .8L 1.7H 1.5L HH       \\
  Q                     & [fgred]  HLHHHLL                  \\
  $\overline{\mbox{Q}}$ & [fgred]  LHLLLHH                  \\
\extracode
 \makeatletter
 \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  % Draw shaded backgrounds
  \shade [right color=bgblue,left color=white]
     (7,-8.45) rectangle (-2,-4.6);
  \shade [right color=bgred,left color=white]
     (7,-12.8) rectangle (-2,-8.6);
  % Add background grid lines
  \begin{scope}[gray,semitransparent,semithick]
    \horlines{}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,6}
      \draw (\x,1) -- (\x,-12.8);
    % similar: \vertlines{1,...,6}
  \end{scope}
  % Add labels
  \node [anchor=south east,inner sep=0pt]
    at (7,-8.45) {\tiny clocked};
  \node [anchor=south east,inner sep=0pt,fgred]
    at (7,-12.8) {\tiny positive edge triggered};
 \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikztimingtable}%
%
\end{section} 
\end{document}
```

I am expecting the pdf to show the text first and then the timing diagram, but only the timing diagram is being generated.

Can somebody please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment out

```
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength{\PreviewBorder}{1mm}
```

and all should be fine. The `active` option previews what you have typeset in your `tikzpicture` environment in this case. Also, consider updating your `tikz-timing`. AFAIK, the latest version is `Version v0.7d – 2011/01/09`. Here is the output when the above lines are commented out.

[image]