# Timing Diagram in Latex

Tags: timing-diagrams

Is it possible to draw a timing diagram like that [image]

in Latex?

Comment: `tikz-timing` package?  Search is your friend.

Comment: Literally, google "Timing Diagram in Latex" :). https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100266/ for example or http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tikz-timing/