# Drawing logic level diagrams (not circuits)

Tags: circuitikz

Is there a package or tikz macro I could use to make something like this:

[image]

I'm looking for a way to create the "high"/"low" zig zag line.

Comment: If you don't already know programming in TeX, writing the TikZ code manually should be less work than learning TeX programming (of course you can still choose the latter). An alternative would be to use another programming language to generate the necessary TikZ code

Comment: [How to generate text and timing diagram together using tikz-timing package? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100266/how-to-generate-text-and-timing-diagram-together-using-tikz-timing-package) & [Slow rising edge in timing diagram with tikztimingtable - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321349/slow-rising-edge-in-timing-diagram-with-tikztimingtable) has some examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The waveform picture can absolutely be created with the tikz-timing package.

How about this (you will have to do a bit of cleanup to get the propagation delays right):

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikztimingtable}[%
    timing/slope=0.0,
    timing/.style={x=3ex,y=2ex},
    x=2ex,
    timing/rowdist=3ex,
    timing/name/.style={font=\sffamily}
]
CLK & h 7{LH} \\
S   & hH 6{L} 2{H} 5{L} \\
R   & l 3{L} 4{H} 4{L} 3{H} \\
CLR\_L & h 2{L} 12{H} \\
\end{tikztimingtable}

\end{document}
```

Which produces this:
[image]